# df.to_excel("Filename.xlsx") doesn't generate new excel using Visual Studio Code but it does with Atom? Why?

Tags: python, pandas

I was cleaning an excel file just now (first time writing a cleaning script) and found that Visual Studio Code (VSC) doesn't generate the cleaned spreadsheet. Out of curiosity I tried Atom and the cleaned spreadsheet is generated. Why? Is there anyway or anything I need to modify or package I need to install or import so that VSC will generate the cleaned spreadsheet?

In VSC's terminal, I have done
pip install xlrd openpyxl

Here's the codes that I have from this youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HU0re8UJViM

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file_path = '/Users/User/Documents/Test/office_info.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)

for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = df[column].str.replace(r'\W',"",regex = True)

df.to_excel("removed_characters.xlsx")
```

What else am I missing?

Comment: Vsc and Atom don't do anything, the code you run does. Check what you launch through them in both cases.

Comment: It's helpful that you added your code, but you should also add any error messages, and what output you actually get.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Python construct `for x in some_list` gives you elements `x` you directly interact with. It's not a subscript. So the statement in your loop should probably look more like `column = column.replace(...)`. Now, I'm not sure that'll work, because I would expect you'd also have to iterate over the elements of the column, either using a pandas operator that does it for you, or with an inner loop.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The solution is actually freaking simple as suggested by unityJarvis.

Comment: put your traceback error code in your question. So it can be reopend and checkmarked being finished/answered. End of review.

Comment: @ZF007 there's no error shown in the terminal and as explained above, it's a matter of changing directory (solution provided by unityJarvis). No need to reopen since issue has been resolved.

Comment: If the file is not found at givine filepath you will get a traceback reporting command-line or IDE style error like: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/User/Documents/Test/office_info.xlsx'`. There is no other possibility with current code. Unless you didn't post the full script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try and use the full file path and see if the issue persists. In my experience VS code runs the python script in a different location than where it is saved. So it might be saving the excel file in a different directory than where the script is saved.

Comment: Thanks @ learningHowtoC. I found that the file was created at /Users/User instead of /Users/User/Documents/Test/. Do you know how I may fix this so that VSC creates the excel file to the specified location? Weird that I don't have to specify this in Atom and it automatically saves where the py file is located.

Comment: In vs code, File -> Open folder and choose the folder with the script. Now it uses the current location as it's working directory